# How to Find selected Active cell highlighted with Color and copy the data provided in the cell above to some special assigned cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA so if somebody help me to solve my problem then I shall be really grateful as I am stuck with it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFWBq.jpg)
Please have a look at the attached picture below and if somebody provide me code for VBA then it will be really helpful for me. Task contains following steps.

1-  In row 11 dates are provided in corresponding columns. Like 16/11, 17/11, 18/11 etc.

2-  From row (12 to 29) I have different tasks to do are provided.

My task is.

1-  When I select any cell/ box by filling it with any color the date available in the (row 10) above that cell (automatically goes/copies) to the specified cell mentioned for that task.
For Example: I select Row 21 AQR presentation cell and highlight it by filling it with color so the date above that cell automatically goes/copies to specified cell mentioned above for AQR presentation and similarly I have to do with every cell.

Request:

I need a code that detects the active cell which is highlighted and sends the date above that cell to a specified folder mentioned for that above.

Please see the figure for more clear understanding.

I shall be grateful if somebody help me in providing the code for this.

Comment: I colour cell X21 which is the crossover for task "AQR Presentation/PA release" and 6Dec16.  The macro copies 6Dec16 to cell Y3.  Why cell Y3 for task "AQR ..."?  What if I had coloured cell Y21 or X22?  The value of copying a date to a cell in the header area is unclear to me.  An explanation of your objective might help people here advise on how to achieve that objective.

Comment: Sorry for delayed reply.I only need AQR Presentation row 21 value and row 16 AQR presentation (1st row ) value in the header because I need it to be used in next worksheet.At a time only 1 date is selected in these Rows. Means in Row 21 I can select 1 date at a time and similar is with Row 16 I can select 1 date.For Header I have 2 boxes because these are of my concern.Just need to be focused only on AQR Presentation row 21 value and row 16 AQR presentation (1st row ) value in the header because I need it to be used in next worksheet.

Comment: I still have difficulty understanding this - so in your F21 and X21 are coloured and the header shows the value of X21. Why? Because it is the latest?

Comment: Sorry for that in diagram now can you please see the diagram i have updated a new one . I hope that it will work and important point is I can only have  colored box like X21 not 2 colored boxes in 1 task (e.g AQR Presentation only contain 1 colored box not 2 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe that an exact match on your requirement is possible; certainly I do not know how to provide an exact match.  However, I believe something very similar is possible which I think is more convenient than your request.

You need to use event routines.  Excel identifies “Open workbook”, “Activate worksheet”, “Change selection” and many others as **events**.  For any Excel event, you can write a routine in VBA which Excel will execute when that event occurs.

If you open Excel’s VB Editor and click <kbd>F2</kbd> you get a list of all the classes and their members.  Scroll down the Classes list until you reach “Worksheet”.  The list on the right will display all member of the Worksheet class. Those with a lightning symbol against them are events: Activate, BeforeDelete, BeforeDoubleClick, BeforeRightClick, Calculate and so on.  If you type “excel vba worksheet before double click event” into your favourite search engine, you will get web pages that explain the event and usually give an example of a routine for the event.  I find the documentation a little vague and I usually have to experiment with an unfamiliar event.

I have written event routines for the WorkBook Open event and the Worksheet Activate, Before Right Click and Selection Change events.  Unfortunately, there is no “Worksheet Change Cell Colour” event so I have used the “Worksheet Before Right Click” event instead.

With the VB Editor open, you will see the Project explorer down the left hand side.  If you cannot see it, click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.  What you will see will be something like:

```
- VBAProject(Xxxxx.xlsm)
  - Microsoft Excel Objects
     Sheet1 (Kick off)
     Sheet2 (Sheet2)
     ThisWorkbook
```

You will have more worksheets, perhaps some user forms and some modules but they do not matter for the moment.  If you can see a plus where I have shown a minus, click it to expand the list.  I have created a copy of your kick-off worksheet which I have named “Kick off”.  You probably have a different name but I will call it “Kick off”.  Click “Sheet1 (Kick off)” and a white area will appear to the right.  This is a code area reserved for this worksheet.  There is a similar code area for every worksheet.  If you click “ThisWorkbook”, you will get another code area.  You can use this code area as an ordinary module but I advise against it.  This code area should be reserved for certain workbook level routines.

Place this code within the ThisWorkbook code area:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Workbook_Open()

  If ActiveSheet.Name = "Kick off" Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Worksheets("Kick off").Activate
  End If
End Sub
```

A routine with the name `Workbook_Open` in this code area will be automatically executed when the workbook is opened.  Replace “Kick off” with your name for this worksheet and replace “Sheet1” with the name of any of your other worksheets.

If worksheet “Kick off” was active when the workbook was saved, its Activate routine is not executed automatically when the workbook is opened.  The sole purpose of this code is to force execution of the “kick off” activate routine.

The code below all belongs in the code area for Worksheet “Kick off”.  This code will not do exactly what you want so I will attempt to explain it in sufficient detail for you to adapt it to your requirements,

My code starts with some constants for rows and columns.  For example:

```
  Const RowDate As Long = 11        ' Row holding dates
```

Currently, you have your dates in row 11 but this could easily change as you develop your system.  If you amend your worksheet so row 13 holds the dates, simply update this constant statement and your code is fully updated.  So much easier than scanning your code for all uses of the literal 11.

Next I have some constants for colours.  If you do not like my colours, amend these constant statements.

Next are some Dim statements.  A variable declared within a routine, is destroyed when the routine exits.  A variable declared outside a routine has a longer life.  I do not know if these variables last until the workbook is closed or until another worksheet is activated. It does not matter; they last long enough to allow me to pass values from one call of an event routine to another call.

Next is `Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()`.  If your users switch to another worksheet, this routine will be called automatically when they switch back.  It records the position of the active cell and loads three arrays.  The three arrays and their values are:

```
  Array entries ->    0   1
  RowActionSrc       16  21 
  RowActionDest       2   3
  ColActionDest      25  25
```

The way these arrays are used is a common technique with experienced programmers but might be new to you.  You want special actions to occur if a selection is made on row 16 or 21.  These rows may change and similar actions may be required for other rows later.  By having a single statement load these row numbers into an array, it is easy to change them or add to them.  If a cell on row 16 is selected, you want its date copied to row 2, column 25. If a cell on row 21 is selected, you want its date copied to row 3, column 25.  These destinations may not be what you want but they are easy to change so that does not matter.  I have coded `Worksheet_BeforeRightClick` to use the numbers in these arrays to move the required dates to the required cells.

Stepping over `Worksheet_BeforeRightClick` for the moment, the last routine in this code is `Worksheet_SelectionChange`.  I was not sure if this was a good idea.  The functionality provided by this routine is the cause of most of the complexity in this code.  I have decided to keep the functionality because I believe it is helpful and because it gives a very good demonstration of what event routines can do.  This is an image of my kick off worksheet:

[image: Approximation to OP's Kick off worksheet]

It is a little small but adequate for the purpose and does not exactly match yours but is close enough.  The active cell is currently cell Z21.  You will notice the task and date for this cell are coloured. When I first started, I found it difficult to match the active cell to its task and date.  Colouring the task and the date made it much easier.   This is what `Worksheet_SelectionChange` does.  When the user moves the active cell, this routine is called automatically to remove the colouring from the old task and date and colour the new task and date.  As I said, I believe this functionality is both helpful and a good demonstration of how you can use event routines to tailor the Excel experience.

Returning to `Worksheet_BeforeRightClick`; this is the routine that provides the functionality that is the closest match I can achieve to what you requested.  As I said, there is no event based on colouring a cell.  Even if there was, I am not sure I would find it convenient.  I would have to select the Home tag then Fill Colour then the colour I wanted before the event would be triggered.  With the Before Right Click event, I select the cell I wish to be active using the arrow keys or the mouse or <kbd>F5</kbd> or however I wish. I then click the right mouse key.  The event routine colours the cell with the standard colour and copies the date.

Experiment with my code. Try to work out how it achieves its objectives.  Come back with questions as necessary but the more you can work out for yourself, the quicker you will develop your own skills.

```
Option Explicit

  ' I define these column and row numbers as constants in case they change.
  ' If they do change, one amendment here and the code is updated. If the
  ' literal is used in the code, you have to search for and fix every use
  ' to update the code.
  Const ColDateFirst As Long = 3    ' The first column with a date
  Const ColTaskName As Long = 1     ' Column holding task names
  Const RowDate As Long = 11        ' Row holding dates
  Const RowTaskFirst As Long = 12   ' First row containing tasks

  ' Warning: If you change any of these colours, the values are BBGGRR which
  ' is Excel's standard and not RRGGB which is everyone else's standard.
  Const ClrCrntHeader As Long = &H99CCFF        ' Tan
  Const ClrSelectedCell As Long = &HFFFF&       ' Yellow

  ' The position of the active cell is recorded in these variable so
  ' when the active cell changes the old position is known. This is
  ' necessary to correctly maintain the row and column headers. If
  ' the row and column headers were not highlighted, these variables
  ' would not be needed.
  Dim ColPrev As Long
  Dim RowPrev As Long

  ' These arrays are loaded by Worksheet_Activate().  See that routine
  ' for an explanation of these arrays.
  Dim RowActionSrc() As Variant
  Dim RowActionDest() As Variant
  Dim ColActionDest() As Variant
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

  ' This routine is called when the worksheet is activated (selected)

  ' * If the active cell is within the monitored area, the header row and
  '   column will already be hightlighted. Record the current position of
  '   the active cell in ColPrev and RowPrev.
  ' * Load RowAction and ColAction arrays
  ' * The monitored area is ColDatFirst and right and RowTaskFirst amd down.

  Application.EnableEvents = False

  If ActiveCell.Row >= RowTaskFirst And ActiveCell.Column >= ColDateFirst Then
    ' Active cell was within the monitored area when the workbook was closed or
    ' the user switched to another worksheet. The appropriate row and column
    ' headers will still be highlighted.
    ColPrev = ActiveCell.Column
    RowPrev = ActiveCell.Row
  Else
    ' The active cell was outside the monitored area. No row or column header
    ' is highlighted
    ColPrev = 0
    RowPrev = 0
  End If

  ' If the active cell is right clicked when it is in one of the rows
  ' listed in RowActionSrc:
  '   1) The active cell is coloured ClrSelectedCell
  '   2) The date above the active cell is copied to the row and column
  '      specified in the cell specified by the matching positions
  '      in RowActionDest and ColActionDest.
  RowActionSrc = VBA.Array(16, 21)
  RowActionDest = VBA.Array(2, 3)
  ColActionDest = VBA.Array(25, 25)
  ' For example:
  '  * If cell(16,20) is right clicked, the date in cell(11, 20) is copied
  '    to cell(2,25).
  '  * If cell(21,27) is right clicked, the date in cell(11, 27) is copied
  '    to cell(3,25).


  Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

  ' * The active cell has been right clicked.
  ' * If the active cell is within the monitored area and if active row is
  '   specified in RowActionSrc, copy the data above the active cell to the
  '   specified destination cell.

    Dim CellColoured As Range

  Application.EnableEvents = False

  Dim InxC As Long

  If ActiveCell.Row >= RowTaskFirst And ActiveCell.Column >= ColDateFirst Then
    ' Active cell was within the monitored area
    For InxC = 0 To UBound(RowActionSrc)
      If RowActionSrc(InxC) = ActiveCell.Row Then
        ' The active cell is in a row for which the date above it is to be
        ' copied to a specified destination. In addition, the active cell is
        ' to be coloured

        ' First remove colour from any previously selected cell
        Application.FindFormat.Interior.Color = ClrSelectedCell
        Do While True
          ' What:="*" will only match cells with a value
          ' What:="" will match cells with or without a value
          Set CellColoured = Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Find(What:="", SearchFormat:=True)
          If CellColoured Is Nothing Then
            Exit Do
          End If
          CellColoured.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone    ' Remove colour
          CellColoured.Value = ""                      ' Remove value if any
        Loop

        ' Colour selected cell
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column).Interior.Color = ClrSelectedCell
        ' Move date for active column to specified cell
        Cells(RowActionDest(InxC), ColActionDest(InxC)).Value = Cells(RowDate, ActiveCell.Column).Value
      End If
    Next
  End If

  Cancel = True  ' Surpress default action for Right Click

  Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

  Application.EnableEvents = False

  ' A new cell has been selected; that is, there is a new active cell.

  If ColPrev <> 0 Then
    ' Remove highlighting from previous task name and date
    Cells(RowPrev, ColTaskName).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    Cells(RowDate, ColPrev).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
  End If

  If ActiveCell.Row >= RowTaskFirst And ActiveCell.Column >= ColDateFirst Then
    ' Active cell is within the monitored area
    ColPrev = ActiveCell.Column
    RowPrev = ActiveCell.Row
    ' Highlight task name and date
    Cells(RowPrev, ColTaskName).Interior.Color = ClrCrntHeader
    Cells(RowDate, ColPrev).Interior.Color = ClrCrntHeader
  Else
    ColPrev = 0   ' No previous active cell
    RowPrev = 0
  End If

  Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

**Explanation of additional functionality**

The original code would colour a cell selected with a right click but would not remove the colour from a previously selected cell.  The new code locates any cells in the active row coloured `ClrSelectedCell` (= Yellow = &HFFFF&) and removes the colour and the value if any.

`Find` is normally used to search for values but it is possible to search for formats.  If there is any decent documentation on the format search functionality, I have failed to find it. The extra code has been developed through experimentation rather than by following official instructions.  This code has been tested using Excel 2016 but I have no reason to believe it will not work with earlier versions.

The changes are the inclusion of a new variable (`Dim CellColoured As Range`) and the inclusion of this code just before the newly selected cell is coloured:

```
    Application.FindFormat.Interior.Color = ClrSelectedCell
    Do While True
      ' What:="*" will only match cells with a value
      ' What:="" will match cells with or without a value
      Set CellColoured = Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Find(What:="", SearchFormat:=True)
      If CellColoured Is Nothing Then
        Exit Do
      End If
      CellColoured.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone    ' Remove colour
      CellColoured.Value = ""                      ' Remove value if any
    Loop
```

There should only be one previously coloured cell but this code loops so all previously coloured cells are cleared of colour and value.

Note: I clear the colour using `ColorIndex = xlNone` rather than `Colour = vbWhite`.  If you set the colour of a cell to white, you lose the borders but you do not if you set the colour index to none.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tony Dallimore for all your help. I am doing my homework on it and i will surely ask questions that i have also right now but i will ask after completion. Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you again. I have few questions as I tried the code but there are few issues that I am facing. I tried to solve those by myself but I am still stucked.I am not getting dates copied in the header above means (header (2,25) ,(3,25)) from (21,11) etc. As I can only select one cell in a row for example row 21 I can only select 1 cell but with this code I don’t know why when I selected 2 cells the previous cell is not erased means In 1 row I only want the active cells date to be copied in header and previously highlighted cell in that row automatically should be un-highlighted.

Comment: Easy issue first. "As I can only select one cell in a row for example row 21 I can only select 1 cell but with this code I don’t know why when I selected 2 cells the previous cell is not erased means. In 1 row I only want the active cells date to be copied in header and previously highlighted cell in that row automatically should be un-highlighted." It would be easy to clear the colour from any existing cell on the row. Perhaps I should have realised this was important but I did not. I will update my answer to do this.

Comment: More difficult problem: "I am not getting dates copied ..." The selected cell is being coloured so you are reaching line 92 of the macro: `Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column).Interior.Color = ClrSelectedCell`. Line 93 is not doing what you expect.  Select line 93 and click F9 or click in the margin of line 93. You want the entire line to be brown indicating it is a breakpoint. Select a cell and right click. The macro will stop on line 93.  If you hover over the variables, their current value will appear.  Do those variables have the values you expect?

Comment: still both issues persists really sorry . I tried but still the issues are there.When I select next cell in a row the task name and column date still remains selected and also i am unable to get the date in the specified cell.I am using excel 2013 but it should not be an issue i think.Sorry but can you check once again please.Thanks.

Comment: And also actually when we are selecting new cell then the task name and date above in the active cell is also selected but when we ove to new cell the date and task name of previous cell are still highlighted as the new code you have provided works best for highlight the highlighted cell but not the task name and date of previous cell .Sorry .

Comment: If ColPrev <> 0 Then
    ' Remove highlighting from previous task name and date
    Cells(RowPrev, ColTaskName).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    Cells(RowDate, ColPrev).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
  End If  this should work but i donot know why i am not seeing the action of these lines because these are for what i am saying

Comment: sorry to ask have you checked again please. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I am currently trying to help four people and I am taking you in turns. Please answer my last comment in which I ask you to investigate what is or is not happening. I cannot see you system, you cannot just say my code does not work. You have to be explicit. With the new code, is it not finding the previously selected cells or is it not removing the formatting?

Comment: First of all really sorry for taking your time and thanks a lot to you for your cooperation. The last updated code that you provided me works perfect. I explain you with example the issue. Let’s suppose I choose in row 21 with yellow color under 29/11 date. When I move to another active cell the yellow color from previous cell gets erased that is perfect as I only want 1 cell to be selected in 1 row. But when I move to next active cell the Column date from the previous cell is still highlighted As we only want the row task name and column date of active cell to be highlighted.

Comment: As we want to copy the date of active cell to be copied to some special cells in the header as we specified in excel sheet but I think that I am doing mistake somewhere that unfortunately I am unable to get the date copied in special cell in header when I select some active cell with color. I hope that I remained successful in explaining you the issue. Sorry again if I am wrong somewhere as I requested you before that I am quite new to VBA.

Comment: In the workbook you sent me, the row 19 task is coloured. How is that possible? Have you updated  Have you changed the Action arrays? What are their new values? What happens at the top of `Worksheet_SelectionChange`? Is ColPrev = 0?

Comment: If you are have trouble debugging, perhaps this page will help: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/861/debugging-and-troubleshooting#t=20161129224422925762

Comment: When I debug the code with F8 it only hovers or moves in first sub routine and I am getting value of Col Prev= 0 , and it donot move or shift to 2nd sub routine . I have also attached macro with the sheet that i send to you can you please have a look at that. Sorry for this.

Comment: RowActionSrc = VBA.Array(16, 21),  RowActionDest = VBA.Array(2, 3),
ColActionDest = VBA.Array(25, 25)  No I have not changed the action arrays.    I am using the same code.

Answer (score 0):

Define a function in VBA:

```
Function NOTWHITE(rng As Range) As Boolean
    Application.Volatile
    If rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Or rng.Interior.Color = vbWhite Then
        NOTWHITE = False
    Else
        NOTWHITE = True
    End If
End Function
```

Then put into D12 the following formula and copy-paste to all other cells you wish to behave like that:

```
=IF(NOTWHITE(D12); D$11; "")
```

However you need to recalculate the sheet by F9 after each change.

Comment: This would set any coloured cell in the data area to the date in the same column of row 11.  My reading of the question is that the OP wants an unspecified cell in the header area set to the date in row 11.  If my reading is correct, this function does not help.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eleshar it worked for me but i have an issue can u please let me kow that how to copy the data that i will get from this code incase of True means coloured value into another place as mentioned in diagram in STEP 4 because i want it to detect the coloured value and then copy the date of couloured cell to some other cell assigned. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Tony Dallimore also got it right . I want it to be in some other place means cell.

Comment: Tony Dallimore so can you please suggest some solution as u got it right now . Thx

Comment: @MuhammadNauman Please answer my comment against your question.